# How to get compressed memory back in OS X 10.9 Mavericks?

Tags: mac, memory, compression

I followed the suggestion to disable [compressed memory](https://www.apple.com/osx/advanced-technologies/#memory), now I want to get it back.

I checked the code, it was `4` before disabling.

So, I tried:

`sudo nvram boot-args="vm_compressor=4"`

That was not effective.

Please, how to get the feature back?

Comment: For link purposes: [Disable compressed memory in Mac OS 10.9 Mavericks?](http://superuser.com/q/668114/84988)

Answer (score 5):

You're confusing the *boot argument* `vm_compressor` with the *sysctl variable* `vm.compressor_mode`; they don't correspond in values. As I understand it, this is the mapping:

```
nvram boot-args=""  =>                 sysctl vm.compressor_mode=4  =>  memory compression enabled (normal)
nvram boot-args="vm_compressor=1"  =>  sysctl vm.compressor_mode=1  =>  memory compression disabled
```

To restore the default behavior, either:

- remove the one boot argument from NVRAM; or
- remove all boot arguments, `sudo nvram -d boot-args`

– then restart the Mac.

Comment: Is there any value other than 4 for enabled? In Ask Different: [vm_compressor_mode (vm.compressor_mode) values for enabled compressed memory in OS X](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/118839/8546)